# Joining 2 primary key columns to 1 foreign key column in the same table

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

I have a `jobs` table with a `projectmanagerid` and a `projectdirectorid` e.g

```
jobs
----------------
pk jobid
pk projectmanagerid
pk projectdirectorid
```

Both these id columns need to link to an employees table using the `employeeid` pk as the link. Is this good practice or is there a better way?

```
employees
------------------
pk employeeid
   other stuff
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems OK as long as you're only going to have those two types: Manager and Director. But think about whether you might need to add another employee type, for example Coordinator, in the future. If that's a possibility then you've got a many-to-many relationship between `jobs` and `employees` that you should resolve by using an intermediary junction table, perhaps also adding a third table to describe the employee's role on the job (Manager, Director, ...).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with it and it's perfectly acceptable. The field names are descriptive and thereby signify that you do actually need to have two different FKs pointing at the users table. if it was `x` and `y`, then it'd look weird.

Answer (score 0):

Seems quite reasonable -- and common in many heirarchies -- to have two relationships to the same table. As with all foreign keys, but perhaps even more so in this case, use cascading carefully. I'm guessing that deletion of the manager or director should not result in deletion of the job record.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule of thumb that states a table models an entity/class or the relationship between entities/classes but not both. Therefore, consider creating two relationship tables to model the two relationships, project managers and project directors respectively. I don't recommend Joe Stefanelli's `employee_role_id` approach. I think you will find that the attributes for each role (yes, relationships do indeed have attributes too) will be too different to make the generic table approach to add value.